# Pushing STS project from a local repo to a remote created by different user

Tags: git, github, spring-tool-suite

I have a locally created Maven project on STS (Spring tool suite), that has some commits already. I want to push it to a remote repo created by another user. I didn't fork the project from the remote repo initially. It does not exist on the remote. The remote is an empty repo. I created the project on my local repo. Now my question is how to push it to the remote repo in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add the new repo as a remote on your sandbox and push the branches you want to keep to that repo.

```
git remote add new_origin <new_url>
git push new_origin master
git push new_origin <any other branches you want on the new remote>
```

Now, if you want the new remote to become the upstream for your local branches, as if you had cloned from it, you can add `--set-upstream` to the push command:

```
git push --set-upstream new_origin master
```

Finally, if your local sandbox didn't already have a remote, you can safely use the name `origin` instead of `new_origin` if you prefer.